# How to access a list with an index from a calling function

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# console program.
I have a function that returns a list of objects.

e.g the following will return a list of objects.

```
p.getList();
```

If I already know the index of the object I want to reference from the list, then how to I access this?
For example I want to do the following which obviously is incorrect:

```
p.getList()[Index]
```

This would give me the item in the list at index.

To get around this I have done the following:

```
List<MyObject> mylist = p.getList();
mylist[Index];
```

but the above seems inefficient, to have to create a copy just to reference a value.

Any tips on how I can access?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think a copy would be created? If the implementation of `p.getList()` does not explicitly create a deep copy, you'll get a (copy of the) reference to the list in `p`.

Comment: Why `p.getList()[Index]` is incorrect? how is your list defined?

Comment: [What makes you think `p.getList()[Index]` is incorrect](http://ideone.com/aYQ8Wm)?

Comment: If you use `List<MyObject> myItem = p.getList()[Index];` then it is incorrect, yes. But in general it should give you the `MyObject`instance at index `Index` in the list. What error did you get?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the *list*, but an `item` and you know the `Index` then

```
 var item = p.getList()[Index];
```

syntax is perfectly correct. Please, notice, that `List<T>` is a *reference type*, that's why in case of

```
 var list = p.getList(); // reference copy, not the collection cloning
 var item = list[Index];
 ...
 var otherItem = list[otherIndex];
```

the `var list = p.getList();` adds a miniscule overhead: it's *reference*, not the entire collection is being copied.

Comment: oh hilarious.. I had it right all along. Not sure why it was showing an error before. I've retried it and it works now. By the way, thanks for your explanation pointing out the reference. Good to know!